# My custom express json middleware is not working properly

Tags: node.js, express

i have tried implementing my own middleware which is similar to `app.use(express.json())`

the code is here

```js
const rahul_express={
    json(){
        return (req,res,next)=>{
            let arr=[]
            req.on('data',(chunk)=>{
                arr.push(chunk)
            })
            req.on('end',(fin)=>{
                const parserbody=new Buffer.concat(arr).toString()
                
                req.body=JSON.parse(parserbody)
                console.log(req.body)                
            })
            next() 
        }
    }
}

app.use(rahul_express.json())
```

i have tried parsing the JSON and adding it the req but still in other middleware i can't access the req.body data,i don't know why,any help will be appreciated!

Comment: the code worked when i moved next() to the 'end' listener block, i don't know what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events are called "asynchronously," meaning that the code doesn't wait until the event is emitted.  This means that `next()` is ran **before** the events are finished.

The correct approach to this problem is to use `next()` inside of the `end` event's callback, like so:

```js
req.on('end', (fin) => {
    const parserbody = new Buffer.concat(arr).toString();
    req.body = JSON.parse(parserbody);
    console.log(req.body);
    next();
})
```